# Идентифицировать и стилизовать начало параграфа без класса по признаку комбинации общих символов (CSS, JS)

Tags: javascript, html, css

В коде html есть конструкции: `<p>— Некий рандомный текст.</p>`. У них нет своего класса.

По указанному признаку «тире, пробел, некий рандомный текст.», мне нужно отловить это условие и стилизовать параграф путём назначения ему класса. Например: `<p class="mdashstring">— Некий рандомный текст</p>`. Само собой, цель в том, чтобы остальные параграфы — не имеющие тире и пробела вначале — должны остаться как есть.

Через «голый» CSS это не решается даже условными операторами. Джаваскриптом не владею, поэтому прошу подсказать — какой код js я мог бы применить для решения задачи? Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Ну вот так, например. Ищем по селектору нужные элементы, пробегаемся по ним и смотрим включает ли контент какую-то строку или совпадает с регуляркой (я проверяю строки, начинающиеся с `*`  или `-` ), затем добавляем нужный класс.

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".text p");

elements.forEach((el) => {
  if (el.innerHTML.match(/[\*\-] \w*/)) {
    el.classList.add('styled');
  }

  if (el.innerHTML.includes('ГДЕ ДЕНЬГИ')) {
    el.classList.add('specialStyled');
  }
})
```

```css
.styled {
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.specialStyled {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <p>Hello there!</p>
  <p>- Привет</p>
  <p>ГДЕ ДЕНЬГИ, ЛЕБОВСКИ?!</p>
  <p>* Какие деньги?</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Зачем-же здесь регулярные выражения, если можно использовать просто `startsWith("- ")`?

Comment: Ох... Я так и не разобрался с регекспами `(/[\*\-] \w*/))`. Подставлял наугад то и это, но не поборол. Вы уж извините и спасибо за труд. А вот вариант с `startsWith('— ')` прокатил сразу. Мне предложили такую конструкцию:

`document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('p').forEach(p => {
    if (p.textContent.startsWith('— ')) {
      p.classList.add('mdashstring');
    }
  });
});`

Comment: @XelaNimed Да, но если символ списка один, а не разные. Иначе придётся несколько раз дублировать код